# Set image full screen in android

Tags: android, imageview

My imageView is filling the maximum size horizontally when the phone is in vertical mode. But when I shift it to horizontal mode my imageView does not match pthe arent.  I need the picture to be extended to the borders of the screen.
What I do wrong?

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="5dp">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/picture"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:src="@drawable/keks1"
    />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set ImageView's Background not src.

```
android:background="@drawable/keks1"
```

Answer (score 0):

set ImageView Background. for more information check http://androiddesk.wordpress.com/